# Distinct values as string in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get distinct values from Column "Site1" seperated by comma in the results table. See example in the picture.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Most people here want sample data, and expected result, as formatted text. (Not as images, whether existing or not.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group concat with the seperator comma,

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Site1 SEPARATOR ',') FROM table
```